# Two Grandpa Questions linked with same property?

Tags: word-property

Grandpa is a foodie. Does not mean that he likes everything though.

> He likes Crab  but not Lobster
>
> He likes Roti  but not Naan
>
> He likes Apricot but not Plum

Why is that?

He also said that his likes are related to him (also) liking the following words

> Obituary
>
> Quixotry
>
> Opacity
>
> Outbrag

Can you now figure it out?

Answer (score 5):

Grandpa likes

> the sound of an *r* followed by a vowel,

as seen in

> c**ra**b
> **ro**ti
> ap**ri**cot
> obitua**ry**
> quixot**ry**.

Comment: Interesting but Lobster also has R sound

Comment: @DEEM But not as I describe rot13(sbyybjrq ol n ibjry).

Comment: OK +1 for creative thinking. But he has different likes

Comment: @DEEM There's only a handful of words and little other context provided, so any common property is possibly relevant. Rather than just saying "that wasn't what I was thinking of", adding more examples to narrow it down to just the one rule you have in mind might be a good idea.

Comment: OK. Two more words provided