# Three bad things and all numbers, says Grandpa

Tags: word

"I am looking at this 7 letter word", says Grandpa in a serious tone.

> "It has three really bad words in it- unbroken. Yet, the word itself
>   is an acceptable way of preparing some things", he muttered.
>
> "And each letter, all of them, are numbers- believe it or not".

Should be an easy guess?

Comment: I also know a word that contains three swaer words (one of them is actually an abbreviation) and the whole word is a building.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll take a bite at cracking this hard puzzle with

> **deviled**

It has three really bad words in it

> devil, evil and vile (or viled)

Each letter, all of them, are numbers

> I, V, L, D are Roman numerals and e is Euler's number

It is an acceptable way of preparing

> deviled eggs which are hard-boiled and the yolks mixed with mayonnaise and mustard.

Comment: That was fast. I am now working on a hard puzzle just for you @Tom :)

Comment: @DEEM - I'm a great admirer of Grandpa, I hope not too hard, and can't solve [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81356/two-grandpa-questions-linked-with-same-property).